# How are the prepreg & core selected for a 6 layer (1 oz each) and 93mil PCB thickness?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I would appreciate your help.  How is defined the number of prepreg and Core dielectrics for a 6 layer (1 Oz each) and the total 93 mil tickness of the PCB?

Comment: Most good-quality fab shops will be able to produce whatever stack-up you request, whether it's 5 layers of 18 mil or four 4-mil outer layers and a big fat 74 mil layer in the middle. You might want to ask your fab about what material they keep stocked, especially if you want a layer thicker than 63 mil.

Comment: Why do you need a 93 mils PCB thickness? The standard thickness is 63 mils (1.6mm).

Answer (score 2):

If it is a standard PCB without impedance control on the lines ,the PCB fab house will use the stack up as below .Slight difference will be there from different house on prepreg thickness. That is only a example that you can get for reference.

[image]